# What is $E[E[X|Y]|Y]$?

Tags: random-variable, conditional-expectation

What is $E[E[X|Y]|Y]$. Constant or random variable?

We know that $E[X|Y]$ is a random variable that dou should get epends on Y. Then the last given Y in $E[E[X|Y]|Y]$ should tell you what that Y is, so $E[E[X|Y]|Y]$ is a constant right?

It like saying $E[X|X]$ that should be a constant.

Comment: Where did you find the formula? Are you sure it is not [E(E(X|Y))](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)?

Comment: Its not a formula, It just appeared during one of the steps im doing as part of a proof. Can you tell me if the second |Y is redundant or not?

Comment: I feel like you can just not write it for the fact that you're given Y twitce which is the same as giving it once.

Comment: $E[E[X|Y] | Y]$ is redundant (exactly equal to $E[X|Y]$), but $E[E[X | Y]]$ is not, because you are taking the average value of $E[X|Y]$ over all $Y$. It could be written more clearly as $E_Y[E[X | Y]]$. I think most readers will assume you misquoted the formula; if that's actually what appeared in the proof, then either (a) they may be applying it in some tricky way (i.e. the proof applies $E[...|Y]$ to both sides of an equation or something like that) or (b) there may be a typo.

Answer (score 6):

$\mathrm{E}(X\,|\,X)$ is not a constant, it is equal to $X$. Similarly, $E(E(X\,|\,Y)\,|\,Y)$ is equal to $E(X\,|\,Y)$. How you can explain this is depending on how your definition of conditional expectation is. Informally, $E(X\,|\,Y)$ is a random variable, defined for all outcomes of $Y$, that is equal to the expectation of $X$ given this outcome of $Y$ ($E(X|Y=a)$). Conditioning on $Y$ again is trivial, since that would be a function equal to $E(E(X\,|\,Y)|Y = a)$ for every outcome $a$ of $Y$, so that is equal to $E(X|Y=a)$ for all outcomes, equivalent to conditioning one time.

**EDIT** The important parts from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable_2) I list below. This is not a real explanation, but if you are into the theory already, you may know where this fits in.

1. Definition

Let $\displaystyle g:U\to \mathbb {R} ^{n}$ be a $\Sigma$ -measurable function such that, for every $\displaystyle \Sigma $-measurable function $\displaystyle f:U\to \mathbb {R} ^{n}$,

$$\displaystyle \int g(Y)f(Y)\,dP=\int Xf(Y)\,dP.$$

Then the random variable$\displaystyle g(Y)$, denoted as $\displaystyle \operatorname {E} (X\mid Y)$, is a conditional expectation of X given $\displaystyle Y$ .

2. Why $\mathrm{E}(X|X) = X$?

It's this property:

(Stability) If $\displaystyle X$ is $\displaystyle {\mathcal {H}}$-measurable, then $\displaystyle E(X\mid {\mathcal {H}})=X$.

Comment: You are right about expected value, but conditional expectation is a random variable. There is a difference between those. My explanation is not that clear, so I'll give you that as well.

Comment: There is a difference between $E(Y|Z)$ and $E(Y|Z=boy)$. The latter is a constant, the former is a random variable.

Comment: Why $E[X|Y]$ is a random variable while $E[X]$ is a constant please?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple common definitions/characterizations of the conditional expectation. Personally the one I find most insightful is the least squares characterization, that
$$ \mathbb{E}[X | Y] = g(Y) $$
for  $g$ the solution to
$$ \min_{g} \mathbb{E}[(X - g(Y))^{2}]. $$
In other words, sort of doing a (non-linear) least squares regression of $X$ on $Y$ to solve
$$ X = g(Y) + \epsilon $$
for $\epsilon$ the mean-zero "residual" which is independent of $Y$.

Then we can see that, for any function $f$,
$$ \mathbb{E}[f(Y) | Y] = f(Y), $$
so
$$ \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y] | Y] =\mathbb{E}[g(Y) | Y] = g(Y). $$
This also works for understanding why
$\mathbb{E}[X | X] = X$, and also why
$$ \mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[X | 1] $$
is a constant (or equivalently a constant random variable).

However, I do agree with the commenters that probably the proof meant $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X | Y]]$, which is a constant, and the extra "$ | Y$" was just a typo or something.

Comment: To be more precise, $E[X|Y]$ is the minimizer of $\min_g E[(X - g(Y))^2|Y]$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong The extra "|Y" is not needed, since it would make the "squared-error" quantity a non-constant random variable and thus something we couldn't minimize.